# How to ground an oscilloscope when our home has no ground?

Tags: noise, oscilloscope, grounding

I bought an old used analog oscilloscope last week.
Our home has no ground, so my oscilloscope is not grounded and shows my high-frequency (example 16 MHz of XTAL) wave superimposed on a 50 Hz sinusoidal.

I think this happens because my scope is not grounded. How can I ground my scope when there is no ground in the home? Are there alternatives for electrical grounding?

In fact, I connect the scope's ground and signal to 2 pins of 16 MHz Arduino XTAL. I saw 16 MHz very noisy sinusoidal wave on scope, I played with trigger level so much to decrease the noise but not effected, and when I changed the time division to ms range, I saw 16 MHz sine wave ride on 50 HZ sine wave . Is it possible my scope was faulty or damaged?

Comment: Do you know for a fact your home is not grounded? Or are you guessing from your scope reading? I really doubt your home is not grounded even if in a developing country, though I could be wrong. Is your ground clip actually working? What happens if you just try and measure the voltage across a battery in auto-run mode? Or what happens if you just clip your probe and ground clip together?

Comment: I'd be more concerned about a lack of ground on your home wiring before trying to get the scope reading correctly.

Comment: People have been known to float their scopes on purpose. A dangerous practice, especially when the scope ground is connected to a hot mains. The scope should work fine, show us exactly how you connected it.

Comment: Are you connecting the ground clip of the probe to the ground of the circuit you are measuring? You shouldn't get 50Hz into the scope trace even if the scope is not grounded.

Comment: You probably should run a ground connection from a metallic water pipe, building frame, or a ground rod driven into the earth, for outlets you use for electronic equipment and other such devices.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Yes I'm sure that our home was not grounded, in new buildings about from 10 years ago the grounding became obligatory. Maybe 80% of homes not grounded. I connect the ground of scope to ground of the circuit. Is it possible my scope was faulty or damaged?

Comment: In fact, I connect the scope's ground and signal to 2 pins of 16 MHz Arduino XTAL. I saw 16 MHz very noisy sinusoidal wave on scope, I played with trigger level so much to decrease the noise but not effected, and when I changed the time division to ms range, I saw 16 MHz sine wave ride on 50 HZ sine wave . Is it possible my scope was faulty or damaged?

Comment: I was surprised when using LP filter to converting 100 KHz square wave to sine and the scope showed me a nice pretty sine wave without any problem. the scope is philips pm3296A 400MHz 2-chanel.

Comment: I estimate that hundreds of thousands of Swedish homes are not grounded, and Sweden is hardly a backwards low-tech nation. However, that doesn't mean my scopes display junk. I can't test with my PM3295 though, since its PSU is broken.

Comment: @hadi Is this your first oscilloscope?

Comment: yes this is my first scope and I bought it very cheap, so I guess that was faulty, because the auto Key was not working correctly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should not connect scope ground and signal to the two crystal pins.

Scope ground should be connected to MCU ground pin so you can probe one crystal pin with one probe.

Comment: I went to test it

Comment: I tested it and it worked. Of course, I should have put the probe in 10X mode before testing the 16 MHz frequency, right?

Comment: Yes. As a rule of thumb, use 10x mode by default, unless you know you need/want/must use the 1x mode.